# Scroll content overflow in WPF TabControl

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF `TabControl` which displays `UserControl`s. Some `UserControl`s are larger than the `TabControl` and got clipped, so I modified its template by wrapping the `ContentPresenter` in a `ScrollViewer` with `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` set to `"Auto"`.

The problem with this solution is that relative-sized `UserControl`s hosted by the `TabControl` now gets thousaunds of pixels wider than they are supposed to because the `ScrollViewer` does not restrict their size.

How can I achieve scrolling of content overflow in a WPF `TabControl` without its relative-sized content growing out of proportions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the solution described in this blog post:

[When to scroll? The problem of infinite-sized UI elements inside a ScrollViewer](http://noamlewis.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/when-to-scroll-the-problem-of-infinite-sized-ui-elements-inside-a-scrollviewer/)

To summarize the basic idea:

> So, the solution seems simple enough: we can tell the ScrollViewer to have dual behavior:
>
> - If the available screen size is smaller than some minimum, allow scrolling, and set the size available for the content to be that minimum size.
> - If the available screen size is larger than the minimum, behave like a regular container that gives its children only the space it has on the screen.

Comment: Here's the wayback machine link in case the above link dies: http://web.archive.org/web/20121123092324/http://noamlewis.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/when-to-scroll-the-problem-of-infinite-sized-ui-elements-inside-a-scrollviewer

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix height or width

or

try to put your content control in ScrollViewer

Comment: Fixed height and width is not an option. The contents need to shrink and grow with the available size. As stated in my question, I have already tried wrapping everything in a ScrollViewer, but I don't get the behavior I want.